# DRAC console access using com2 displays garbage characters

Tags: serial-port

We have written an expect script to connect to Dell Drac and reimage the box using image (pxe).

Implementation Details(in expect script) :
ssh to admin@hostname-c
Enter the password
send command to reboot the host
connect com2 (this will redirect the console output of host to terminal)
wait for the message "F12 PXE" and send "F12".

Issue Description:
At times, on connecting to com2, the console starts displaying garbage characters. Hence our scripts are failing.

Any help to resolve this issue are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Dell PowerEdge R310 with an iDRAC 6 card running Lucid. I found some help, and was able to put together a solution, from this question:

[Garbled using from Dell Drac for serial console redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/269382/garbled-using-from-dell-drac-for-serial-console-redirection)